# Sudo rvm, command not found. Rvmsudo doesn't work either. (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I've got this problem with ruby versions. I've been looking for a solution, but none of the solutions I've found worked for me.

System is Ubuntu 13.10.

If I type

> ruby -v

Then I got

> ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

But if I type

> sudo ruby -v

Then I got

> ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

If I'm trying to change the version using sudo rvm use  I'm getting:

> sudo: rvm: command not found

Rvmsudo get's me this:

> Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:
>
> export rvmsudo_secure_path=1
>
> to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it >persistent.
>
> In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:
>
> export rvmsudo_secure_path=0
>
> to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

I've tried to type in those exports, but it didn't change anything. Typing them with "sudo", gives back "export:command not found".

I've already tried reinstaling everything, didn't help. It's a 6 hours now, that I can't find an answer.

Comment: Where did you install rvm? Globally (`/usr/local/...` for example), or in your home directory?

Comment: In my home directory (/home/username/.rvm).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you do not have `rvm` correctly installed. To install `rvm`, please do as follows:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | (sudo) bash -s stable --ruby -s stable --rails 
$ curl -L https://get-git.rvm.io | bash
```

Single-User Install Location: `~/.rvm/`
Multi-User Install Location: `/usr/local/rvm`

Then in Linux, try `vim ~/.bashrc` and at the end of it add below settings:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This loads RVM into a shell session.
Then, reload to take effect:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
$ source ~/.bashrc              # in Linux
$ source ~/.bash_profile        # in MacOS 
$ type rvm |head -1
```

if it shows `rvm is a function` then you have rvm installed successfully.

Comment: It shows that rvm is a function, but the problem still exists.